# Aftershot Pro 3 not importing CR2 images despite workarounds

Tags: import

Using Windows 10 and importing my CR2 images to a folder on HDD from a memory card.

Selecting folder for import has no issues. "Scan folder" and "Import" dialogues open, run up to 30 briefly then stop.

Tried the workaround by enabling/disabling image profiles through the import/cache function. Same issue.

Tried installing camera profile for the SLR in question (T6s) and repeated above process. Same 30 images are imported, no more no less. They have almost identical metadata and were captured on the same camera...

I installed this software as a good DAM alternative to LR but these issues are repeated, and one of the reasons I requested a refund for the Aftershot Pro software last time.

Comment: Have you contacted support by the sellers of Aftershot Pro 3?

Comment: I have encountered issues in the past with its use of *Hardware Acceleration* and certain graphics cards. Check **File/Preferences/Hardware Acceleration** and make sure its disabled.